# Video background in delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm in Delphi 2010 and doing a PAT , would like to know how i can get a video to play in the background of my main menu of my game.

Comment: What is a PAT? Also, questions of a general nature are not appropriate here. Please use something like [Delphi Praxis](https://en.delphipraxis.net) for that.

Answer (score 0):

The `TAnimation` control has [some pretty severe limitations by today's standards](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050216-00/?p=36433), but its an option.

Your better choice is to simply use a `TWebBrowser`, and give it HTML that contains a `<video>` element that points to your `.mp4` on the user's drive.

Comment: hey thanks , I just messed around with it and i wrote some code that changes out the image file constantly to make it a video just having problems with it making other images flash cause its updating so much

Comment: Set `DoubleBuffered := True` on your form/paintbox/panel/whatever it is doing the drawing

Comment: Don't think DoubleBuffered is going to help here at all.